# Catching Broadcast Intent depending on specific filename ending

Tags: android, opengl-es

I've created an obj viewer (to view 3d models) inside my app and want this functionality to share with other apps. OBJ Files typically end with .obj. Can somebody describe me in short on which broadcast I have to listen to, to offer my 3d viewer, everytime the user deals with such files?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting something like this in your androidmanifest.xml in your activity should work:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:mimeType="*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.obj" />
    <data android:host="*" />
</intent-filter>
```

If you have a mime type then you should fill that in as well so it works if the extension is wrong but the mime-type is correct.

Comment: That is an invalid MIME type.  The wildcard MIME type is "\*/\*".

Comment: On wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file), theres `application/x-tgif`? stated as mime-type. Is this correct for putting it into `<data android:mimeType="application/x-tgif?" />` ?

Comment: I'm not sure about that one I've seen other sites refer to "model/obj"